# How to use value from AJAX to PHP

Tags: php, ajax

Is it possible to pass value from ajax like:

```
$sql = "SELECT * from table WHERE ID=$('#id').val()";
```

Comment: Well, yes. That's the entire point of Ajax. (The only issue is that the code isn't remotely Ajaxy).

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot do something like this. If you really want to pass a value form your ajax or javascript eight you have to make ajax call or you can pass it through html post/get method. You can manipulate html to send get/post using javascript easily.

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible.

You can submit the value to a server page (eg : PHP page) by using [jquery post](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)  and then only you will get the value in PHP page.

Check this simple [tutorial](http://www.formget.com/jquery-post-data/)

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this way too.

Concatenate the `sql query` and `value`, and pass it to some other page.

```
<?

$('#id').click(function(){
    var OrderId=$('#id').val();
    var sqlStmt="SELECT * from table WHERE ID=";
    var sqlQuery = sqlStmt+OrderId;

    $.ajax({url:"AjaxPage.php?sqlQuery="+sqlQuery,cache:false,success:function(result){
        alert(success);
    }});

});

?>
```

**AjaxPage.php**

```
<?
$sqlQuery = $_GET['sqlQuery'];

echo $sqlQuery;

?>
```

Comment: Passing arbitrary SQL to a database server via javascript sounds like a horrible security risk.  Just saying.

Comment: Question was like that only.  I just gave my idea. Requirement is like that only. @EikePierstorff

Comment: Yes. That's why it's a comment, not a downvote. I think it is still a good idea to point this out, else the OP might try to implement your answer.